# SP Field.Hidden property not hiding?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, client-object-model

I have set the property `.Hidden` of one field to `$true`.

```
$field=$List.Fields.GetByTitle("Business Phone")
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$field.Hidden=$true
```

The change has been applied successfully and if I check that property `$field.Hidden` shows `$true`.

The result is that when I am trying to add a new item to my list, the field is not shown, which is expected and desired, but it still exists in the default view and I can add it to a new view.
According to [MSDN description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979575(v=office.15).aspx) "If TRUE, the field is **completely** hidden from the user interface. Setting ReadOnly to TRUE means the field is not displayed in New or Edit forms but can still be included in views."

- Not a required field. It is one of the default fields that comes with a contact list but it is not a required one.
- Name is correct. It is certainly this column, not another one with similar name/internal name, that I am updating. Other changes (like description) are visible in GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the field display by using other properties for each form (new, edit and display form). You can overwrite them by using this code :

```
$field=$List.Fields.GetByTitle("Business Phone")
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$field.SetShowInDisplayForm($false)
$field.SetShowInEditForm($false)
$field.SetShowInNewForm($false)

$Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Don't forget to launch the ExecuteQuery method.

Comment: I'm getting "Property 'ShowInDisplayForm' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable." for all the three properties. Are you sure they are available for SharePoint Online?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I've fixed the code and tested it on my office 365 portal. Validate if it's ok ;)

Comment: Ok, valid. The field disappeared from the Edit/Display/New form but it is still in the default view, not hidden completely from GUI. I'm starting to think it's by design, only the documentation is misleading.

Comment: You can edit the default view programmatically, but If you could do it form the interface it would be better (and cleaner).

Comment: Yes, I could, but it doesn't answer the question why a field that is supposedly "completely hidden" is still present in the views. What else is exempt and where could I find the documentation for it?

Comment: First of all, you need to update the field before calling the ExecuteQuery method :

`$field.Hidden=$false

$field.Update()

$Context.ExecuteQuery();`

Secondly, if the field has already been added to the view, and then you set it to be hidden, the field will disappear from the columns list in the list settings page, but will remain visible in the view. You need to remove it from the view before setting it to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify following:

1) Go to List Settings > Advanced Settings:

2) Select Yes on Allow management of content types?

3) Click on one of the existing content types under the Content Type section

4)Next, click on the column you intend to hide and check if following setting is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting exactly the same results. Did your columns completely disappear?